# Using replaceAll to remove part of XPath expression

Tags: java, regex, xpath

```
String xpath = "A/B/C[Hello world]/D";
```

In the above string I have to replace the square brackets and the content between it.
Final output should be: `A/B/C/D`.

I have written the below code but it does not work if there is a a space between `Hello` and `World`:

```
String Xpath1 = xpath.replaceAll("\\[[\\S]+\\]", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches all non-whitespace characters.  Therefore, it will not match a space.

It sounds like you actually want to match all characters except `]`:

```
[^\\]]
```

Comment: I just want to make a final output as A/B/C/D being Inputt as "A/B/C[Hello world]/D". My Hello World Contains Space.

Comment: @RahulJain: Then why did you write a regex that specifically doesn't match spaces?

Comment: I dont know What i sould writ in regex can you please let me know

Comment: @RahulJain: Read my answer.  You need to understand regexes.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
String xpathResult = xpath.replaceAll("\\[.*\\]", "");
```